# Matlab: how to run several optimizations in parallel but stop if enough have converged?

Tags: convergence-divergence, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

So I have an optimization problem for which I use fmincon and, rarely, it gets stuck (in the objective function). So what I want to do is run, say, 4 parallel optimizations and stop when 3 have converged to the stopping criteria of fmincon.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Seb